# A problem on pigeon hole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

The question is to show that

> there is a power of $2$ whose decimal representation starts with the digits $1999$.

*[Hint : apply pigeon hole principle]*

How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem), which says the multiples of an irrational number have their fractional parts equidistributed in the unit interval.  Given $n=2^k$ we have $\log_{10}n=k\log_{10}2$.  We know that $\log_{10}2$ is irrational.  We then just have to claim the existence of a $k$ such that the fractional part of $k\log_{10}2$ is between $\log_{10}1.999$ and $\log_{10}2$

Comment: I don't really understand your solution. Are you using Dirichlet's approximation theorem?

Comment: I put in the Wikipedia reference to the equidistribution theorem.  No, it is not the approxiimation theorem.  I don't care how close we are to a rational, just that we have on number in the interval claimed.

Comment: If I claim that your same reasoning applies to any number $abcd $ with  $a\ne0$ other than $1999$ , am I wrong? It is then true that for all $N$ of $n$ digits there exists $ n $ such that $ 2 ^ n$ begins with $N$?

Comment: @Piquito:  that is correct.  There was nothing special about 1999, except probably the year the problem was asked.

Comment: Thank you. I have an empirical calculation of a "counterexample" certainly wrong,

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete Ross Millikan's answer (+1 to him) we may compute the first terms of the continued fraction of $\log_{10} 2$ and get
$$ \log_{10}2 = [0;3, 3, 9, 2, 2, 4, \color{red}{6}, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 18,\ldots]$$
and by truncating the continued fraction at the highlighted term we get
$$ 13301\log_{10}2 = 4004-\varepsilon,\qquad 0<\varepsilon<3\cdot 10^{-5} $$
hence $\color{red}{2^{13302}}$ is a number with the wanted property.

---

*Small addendedum*: a proof of the irrationality of $\alpha=\log_{10}(2)$. Assuming $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have $10^p=2^q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{N}^+$, but while $5\mid 10^p$, $5\nmid 2^q$, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: If I claim that Ross Millikan's reasoning applies to any number $abcd $ with  $a\ne0$ other than $1999$ , am I wrong? It is then true that for all $N$ of $n$ digits there exists $ n $ such that $ 2 ^ n$ begins with $N$?. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito: that is certainly true. The irrationality of $\log_{10} 2$ implies the equidistribution of $\{ n \log_{10} 2\}$, which on its turn implies the density of $\{n\log_{10} 2\}$ in $(0,1)$ (here $\{ x\}$ stands for the fractional part of $x$)

Comment: Thank you. I have an empirical calculation of a "counterexample" certainly wrong,